# Geared Motor vs Direct drive with external gearbox

Tags: motors, gears, torque

I'm looking to buy a small DC motor (~12W) which rotates at around 60rpm.

I have two options:

- Get a geared motor which has an integrated gear box such that the output shaft rotated at 60rpm.
- Get a direct drive motor and then 3D print some plastic gears with a corresponding number of teeth that gives the required output.

The advantage of the first route is that everything comes prepackaged and thus there's no additional components needed.

However, the second has the advantage that there seems to be a greater choice of motors open to me and with a custom gear set, I can choose any.

Are there any other factors I should consider when deciding between the two options?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, your ability to manufacture gears

Comment: The issue isn't really the gears...you can buy gears. It's arranging the gears to do what you want. So you probably want to buy as many of the gears as possible but instead 3D print the gear case itself. 3D printable plastics aren't the best materials for gears anyways. Even traditional machined plastic gears can leave something to be desired in some applications. 3D print the gear case and buy the gears, shafts, bearings, and bushings so you don't have to sacrifice as much material properties for of fabrication ease. Keep the 3D printing to the parts that needs user tailoring the most.

Comment: A small 12V DC motor could also be spinning tens of thousands of RPM which means a gear somewhere in your gearbox is going to be spinning that fast. A 3D printed gear isn't going to hold up to that very well so you want at least one traditionally manufactured gear in there (and probably a few more near the gearbox input), in any case.